# Half columns in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns, grid-layout

I couldn't figure out how to make the bootstrap column like this:

```
col 3 | col 4.5 | col 4.5
```

Comment: have tried offset. but is not what i need.

Comment: I have created a [custom bootstrap 4.0 extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026855/can-i-give-the-col-md-1-5-in-bootstrap/66729048#66729048) that allows adding half and quarter of column.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You can try this :

*Just split a col-9 in 2 parts.*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/128927

**HTML** :

```
   <div class="col-xs-3">  col-xs-3 </div>
   <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-4.5</div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-4.5  </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me! I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap 3 and I'm using col-md-9 and want it split into two equal parts! Any ideas? :(-

Comment: @Ciwan col-md is just for 'medium' and larger screen, the fact to use col-xs makes it works for all device. Instead of say 'it doesnt work' make a fiddle and show what's not working....

Comment: So there is no wat to do like a `width: 80%;` inside a col-md-6 (if for example you want so whitespace on the right side)

Comment: Great answer for general divs/elements, however it doesn't seem applicable for <td> elements in a tables.

Comment: In the "col-xs-6" is there a reason why "6" is used as opposed to some other value? Is there a relationship between "6" and the "col-9"?

Comment: @Genki One row is splitted in 12 parts(cols), So a col-9 split in 2 equals parts makes two cols of 4.5

Comment: @pbenard Yes, I understand that one Bootstrap row is split into 12 columns, and I understand that if a 12-col row were split in 2, that would be two, 6-col divs.  But the answer given is that dividing "col-9" into 2 = 4.5, so therefore use "col-6".   Why "6"???  If 4.5 were rounded up to "col-5", or down to "col-4," that would make sense. Why is 9 split into 2 = 6?

Comment: @genki, because the asker wanted two col-4.5 so =>   9 * (6/12) = 4.5 ....
I can't be clearer...

Comment: @pbenard I'm new to TWBS. What's confusing me is that in the OP's example, the first <div> already uses **3** columns, so there are only **9** columns remaining. Dividing those 9 by 2 = **4.5** cols -- makes sense.  So, I don't understand why **6** gets used. You gave "9 * (**6** divided by 12)" but I don't understand why **6** shows up. If the question was, "How to divide 12 cols in half?" the answer would obviously be 6. I'm not seeing why "Divide the 9 remaining columns in half = 6."  Maybe someone can explain the logic that this newbie is missing :-)

Comment: @Genki, In the remaining 9 cols, a new .row is setted, so, just see this as a king of percentage.... 100% of col.9 is equal to 12 cols... So if you wants 2 cols of 50% you have to make 2 col-6 because (6/12 = 50%), the row is applicated to the parent container.... I sugget you to read the doc, especially this part : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: @pbenard  AHH -- that new .row was what I was missing. Now I get it.  Thanks for hanging in there with me!

Comment: col 5.5 | col 1 | col 5.5

Comment: There are no bootstrap solution for your case, you have to create your own width in percent (5.5/12*100) or use your own customized bootstrap (v3.3) and compile it with 24 columns.... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/