# Can I give the col-md-1.5 in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to adjust the columns in Twitter Boοtstrap.

I know in bootstrap there are 12 columns grid. Is there any way to manipulate the grids to have 1.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 instead of 3 3 3 3?

Comment: As @bodi0 correctly said, it is not possible. You either have to extent Bootstrap's grid system (you can search and find various solutions) or use nested rows e.g. http://www.bootply.com/dd50he9tGe. In the case of nested rows you might not always get the exact result but a similar one.

Comment: @TasosK. your Example Worked for me you can write it in Answer I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: That's nice, I posted an answer

Comment: If using v4, check out this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838552/4050261

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As [@bodi0 correctly said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30026949/2851870), it is not possible. You either have to extent Bootstrap's grid system (you can search and find various solutions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955398/2851870) is a 7-column example) or use nested rows e.g. http://bootply.com/dd50he9tGe.

In the case of nested rows you might not always get the exact result but a similar one

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">1.67 (close to 1.5)</div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">3.33 (close to 3.5)</div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">3.5</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">3.5</div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 121):

You cloud also simply override the width of the Column...

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="width: 12.499999995%"></div>
```

Since `col-md-1` is of width 8.33333333%; simply multiply 8.33333333 * 1.5 and set it as your width.

in `bootstrap 4`, you will have to override flex and max-width property too:

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="width: 12.499999995%;
    flex: 0 0 12.499%;max-width: 12.499%;"></div>
```

Comment: but `ml-sm-auto` class will still ignore this custom width value :/ (so page responsivness will break)

Comment: Nice, but why didn't you just use 12.5, as that's the actual exact result? :)

Comment: Works perfectly - had spent hours trying to center align a 3 divs forever! Thank you!

Comment: just tested your solution for bootstrap 4 with bootstrap 5.3 and still works!

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is **no** (technically you can give whatever name of the class you want, but this will have no effect, unless you define your own CSS class - and remember - **no dots** in the class selector). The long answer is again **no**, because [Bootstrap includes a responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic), mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately **scales up to 12 columns** as the device or view port size increases.

Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
- Predefined grid classes like `.row` and `.col-xs-4` are available for quickly making grid layouts. Less mixins can also be used for more semantic layouts.
- Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on `.rows`.
- Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three `.col-xs-4`.
- If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.
- Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any `.col-md-*` class to an element will **not only affect** its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a `.col-lg-*` class is not present.

A possible solution to your problem is to define your own CSS class with **desired width**, let's say `.col-half{width:XXXem !important}` then add this class to elements you want along with original Bootstrap CSS classes.

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 4 uses flex-box and you can create your own column definitions

This is close to a 1.5, tweak to your own needs.

```
.col-1-5 {
    flex: 0 0 12.3%;
    max-width: 12.3%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have created a [custom bootstrap extension](https://github.com/HoomanBahreini/bootstrap-half-and-quarter-grid/blob/main/README.md) that allows you to use the following classes:

```
// replace * with a number between 0 and 11
col-*-1qtr
col-*-half
col-*-3qtr
```

Also note that you can use responsive classes, such as:

- `col-sm-2-half` (2.5)
- `col-md-0-3qtr` (0.75)
- `col-lg-11-1qtr` (11.25)
- `col-xl-5-half` (5.5)

Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hoomanbahreini/bootstrap-half-and-quarter-grid/fractional-grid.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Using fraction of columns</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2-3qtr bg-success">col-2-3qtr (2.75)</div>
    <div class="col-3-1qtr bg-warning">col-3-1qtr (3.25)</div>
    <div class="col-3-half bg-success">col-3-half (3.5)</div>
    <div class="col-2-half bg-warning">col-2-half (2.5)</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Rex Bloom response I have write a bootstrap helper:

```
//8,33333333% col-1

.extra-col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-0-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 4.16666667%;
  max-width: 4.16666667%;
}

.col-1-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 12.5%;
  max-width: 12.5%;
}

.col-2-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 20.833333325%;
  max-width: 20.833333325%;
}

.col-3-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 29.166666655%;
  max-width: 29.166666655%;
}

.col-4-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 37.499999985%;
  max-width: 37.499999985%;
}

.col-5-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 45.833333315%;
  max-width: 45.833333315%;
}

.col-6-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 54.166666645%;
  max-width: 54.166666645%;
}

.col-7-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 62.499999975%;
  max-width: 62.499999975%;
}

.col-8-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 70.833333305%;
  max-width: 70.833333305%;
}

.col-9-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 79.166666635%;
  max-width: 79.166666635%;
}

.col-10-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 87.499999965%;
  max-width: 87.499999965%;
}

.col-11-5 {
  @extend .extra-col;
  flex: 0 0 95.8333333%;
  max-width: 95.8333333%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create new classes to overwrite the width. See [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akqfvxzy/1/) for working code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-1-5">
    <div class="box">
      box 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-3-5">
    <div class="box">
      box 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-3-5">
    <div class="box">
      box 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-3-5">
    <div class="box">
      box 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.col-xs-1-5 {
  width: 12.49995%;
}
.col-xs-3-5 {
  width: 29.16655%;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has column offsets, so if you want columns with equal width without specifying size use this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

Also check out this link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned in Bootstrap 3, you can use nest/embed techniques.

However it is becoming more obvious to use pretty awesome feature from  Bootstrap 4 now. you simple have the option to use the `col-{breakpoint}-auto` classes (e.g. `col-md-auto`) to make columns size itself automatically based on the natural width of its content. check [this for example](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#variable-width-content)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code inside col-md-3 , col-md-9

```
.col-side-right{
  flex: 0 0 20% !important;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.col-side-left{
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not Bootstrap Standard to give col-md-1.5 and you can not edit bootstrap.min.css because is not right way. 
you can create like this http://www.bootply.com/125259

Answer (score -3):

This question is quite old, but I have made it that way (in TYPO3).

Firstly, I have made a own accessible css-class which I can choose on every content element manually.

Then, I have made a outer three column element with 11 columns (1 - 9 - 1), finally, I have modified the column width of the first and third column with CSS to 12.499999995%.