# is there a way to do 1.5 and 8.5 and 2 for bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap grid. And col-sm-1 is too small but col-sm-2 is too big. I would like to have exact middle one, col-sm-1.5. But when I do it, the whole bootstrap grid collapses. Is there a way to do such grid system?

Comment: I think you could use `col-sm-2` and add a child element with width = 75%?

Comment: @SalmanA then I have to change everything for other parts as well, i like the way col-sm8 and col-sm-2 is right now

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You would have to extent Bootstrap's grid system (you can search and find various solutions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955398/2851870) is a 7-column example) or use nested rows e.g. http://bootply.com/dd50he9tGe.

Source: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026855/can-i-give-the-col-md-1-5-in-bootstrap)

Comment: if I extent it then the best part of bootstrap dissapears; "works in mobile"