# How to apply col-*-offset in decimal with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, dom, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to apply an offset in decimals. In my case I need an offset of 3.5.
I don't think `col-xs-offset-3.5` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I give the col-md-1.5 in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026855/can-i-give-the-col-md-1-5-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a column of 5 and center it horizontally. That should give you an offset of 3.5 before and after.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 mx-auto">
      col-5
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

[image]

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/z29q1j5m/