# How can I set decimal width for a column in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, dashboard

I want to set a decimal width for a `column()` element in my R Shiny dashboard. For example, I need 5 columns, hence I require a width of 2.4 each.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shiny's column widths are based on the [Bootstrap 12-wide grid system](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html). You can only specify integers. However, you can [nest multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027585/9841389) to achive a fine grained layout.

Here is an example regarding nested columns:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  p(),
  column(4, p(), style = "background-color: red;"),
  column(4, p(), style = "background-color: green;"),
  column(
    4,
    column(4, p(), style = "background-color: red;"),
    column(7, p(), style = "background-color: green;"),
    column(1, p(), style = "background-color: blue;")
  ),
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

As an alternative you might want to check `?splitLayout` which accepts CSS units:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(splitLayout(
  p("red", style = "background-color: red;"),
  p("green", style = "background-color: green;"),
  p("blue", style = "background-color: blue;"),
  p("yellow", style = "background-color: yellow;"),
  p("orange", style = "background-color: orange;"),
  cellWidths = "20%"
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]