# How to get half columns in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I need a 2.5 column and a 9.5 column in Bootstrap 3. Can somebody please give me a solution? The only answer i've found is a partition of 3 columns. i need 2 half-columns.

Comment: you should right custom width styles for that

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: I just leave this here (*this to get 30 chars*): http://stackoverflow.com/a/22986836/1549628

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the bootstrap sass files you can do it this way:

```
.col-md-half {
   @extend .col-md-1;
   width: percentage((0.5 / $grid-columns));
}
```

This is a similar to Ardee Aram's solution but makes use of the bootstrap $grid-columns variable instead.

Comment: I did a similar thing with LESS:
.col-sm-push-half{
  &:extend(.col-sm-push-1);
 left: percentage((1.5 / @grid-columns));
}

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if creating nested columns would work?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background:red">
        Column spans two
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:pink">
        column spans 2.5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/5d5rvba1/

Something to play with anyway... :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to produce half-columns:

```
.col-md-half {
   @extend .col-md-1;
   width: 4.166666667%;
}
```

In case you are wondering, a column is 100% / 12 = 8.3333%. So a half-column is half that.

Comment: half of 8.333 ~= 4.167

Comment: Thanks @maschwenk! Edited my answer.